# Gitlab read_api token has more permissions than expected

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Im using gitlab API token with read_api permission only.
Once i tried to get a source code file , it return me the data successfully (i was using this endpoint projects/%s/repository/files/%s/raw).

im expecting that it will fail to get this data, i thought from documentation that we need to have read_repository permission to get source code data.

is it possible that read_api permission gives access to the repository files? If so, what it the target of read_repository permission?

is it possible to decrease the permissions for the token? how to disable getting source code data with this token?